# Sorting data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on data frames using pandas in python, I have a sample data frame which looks like this,

```
      R     S       T Percentage   range 
0    34  1234      67  0.78       76-100
1  4326   223   56734  0.78       76-100
2   653  2312    3466  0.45       26-50
3  3461    45  546234  0.20       0-25
4  3464  5772     565  0.45       26-50
```

I want to sort this data frame based on the column "range", 
Something like this is expected,

```
   R       S     T     Percentage   range 
0  3461    45  546234   0.20        0-25
1  653    2312   3466   0.45       26-50
2  3464   5772   565    0.45       26-50
3  34     1234    67    0.78       76-100
4  4326   223   56734   0.78       76-100
```

I don't want to disturb all the values which are row-wise in the data frames but  I want sort it out taking column "Range".

How am I able to achieve this ? Please help me

Comment: I tried,    'data.sort_values('Percentage')'                                                
                                                                                                                
But it is giving error : 
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Comment: sort_values has be refactored in v 0.17. Are you on a newer version?